# Dropbox Core SDK iOS searchPath multiple keywords

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, dropbox, dropbox-api

since there is no documentation about Dropbox core SDK for iOS I would like to be able to retrieve all metadata of images files store in a user dropbox. I do not want to use the call

`-(void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path;` and do it recursively until I finish to parse all directories.

I realy want to use the:

`- (void)searchPath:(NSString*)path forKeyword:(NSString*)keyword;`

But is there any ways to pass multiple keywords ? Like "jpeg" and "png" ?

I just did refactor my code to do not call directly the Dropbox API, I really want to go through the SDK.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to pass multiple keywords to the search method (as the API endpoint itself doesn't support that anyway). Instead you can call the method multiple times, once for each keyword, and merge the results together.

Alternatively, you can use `loadDelta` to get all of the available metadata:

```
/* Loads a list of files (represented as DBDeltaEntry objects) that have changed since the cursor was generated */
- (void)loadDelta:(NSString *)cursor;
```

This is preferable to calling `loadMetadata` recursively, and then you can search the returned metadata in memory. You can find more information about using delta [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta).